# Can I FOREACH by the args which is combination of $query_string and another args?

Tags: wordpress

I can show expected posts by $args_normal in below code.  However, I can not foreach by $args_normal.  When I try foreach it, it shows post title repeatedly.  How can I foreach it correctly?

```
<?php
$week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7days'));
$name= get_search_query();
global $query_string;
$args = $query_string;
parse_str( $args, $args );
$args_normal = $args + array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key'=> '2a',
                    'value' => array('2020-02-01' , $week),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type' => 'DATE',
                    ), 
                    ), 

);
?>

<?php $my_posts = get_posts($args_normal);

if ( $my_posts ) {
foreach( $my_posts as $post ) {
$title = get_the_title( $post->ID);
}}
echo $title;
var_dump($my_posts);
?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have three `foreach` statements? Why not just use the first one to output the titles? If you `var_dump( $my_posts)` what data is shown?

Comment: Thank you disinfor.  I editted code again.  Now, echo $title shows only 1 post tile.  var_dump($my_posts) shows all posts information following meta query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding as an answer since a comment would be too long:

1. In your updated code, you are only getting one title from `echo $title` because it's outside of the `foreach`, so it will only give you the last one.
2. When you `var_dump($my_posts)`, it's better to do it (this is really an opinion) immediately after `$my_posts = get_posts($args_normal); var_dump($my_posts)`, since you want to see the data your getting BEFORE you try and loop through it.

```
// Get your posts.
$my_posts = get_posts($args_normal);

// If you have posts
if ( $my_posts ) {
    // Loop through the posts
    foreach( $my_posts as $post ) {
       // no need to assign to a variable, just echo get_the_title()
       echo get_the_title( $post->ID);
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Now I understand it completely!!!

Comment: It would be much appreciated to help another probelm related with above code.  Foreach function skips some posts.  I like to ask you as job if possible.  How can I ask you??

Comment: What posts does it skip? You can open up a new question and I can help you there.

Comment: Thank you!!!  Now I made another question with more information "Combination of search result($query String) with added $args does not show all posts."

Comment: Maybe you are same name in wordpress.org?  Can I contact you through there so that I can ask you as formally?